# Pandas equivalent of SQL case when statement to create new variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df:

```
data = np.array([[np.nan, 0], [2, 0], [np.nan, 1]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns = ['a', 'b'])
```

which looks like this:

```
     a    b
    --------
0   NaN  0.0
1   2.0  0.0
2   NaN  1.0
```

My **goal** is to create a third column "c" that has a value of 1 when column "a" is equal to NaN and column "b" is equal to 0. "c" would be 0 otherwise. The simple SQL case statement would be:

```
(CASE WHEN a IS NULL AND b = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS C
```

The **desired output** is this:

```
     a    b   c
    -----------
0   NaN  0.0  1
1   2.0  0.0  0
2   NaN  1.0  0
```

My (wrong) try:

```
df['c'] = np.where(df['a']==np.nan & df['b'] == 0, 1, 0)
```

Many thx.

Comment: What was wrong with your try?

Comment: "cannot compare a dtyped [int64] array with a scalar of type [float]"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there, instead use `np.where(df['a'].isnull() & (df['b'] == 0), 1, 0)` for null check.

Alternatively,

```
In [258]: df['c'] = (df['a'].isnull() & (df['b'] == 0)).astype(int)

In [259]: df
Out[259]:
     a    b  c
0  NaN  0.0  1
1  2.0  0.0  0
2  NaN  1.0  0
```

Comment: Thanks John. First statement with np.where is correct. But the alternative seems to be wrong. It gives you c = [1, 1, 0] when it should be [1, 0, 0]. Check it out pls

Comment: Hey @John Galt, actually 'c' column  should have values as [1,0,0].

Answer (score 15):

For more control on conditions use np.select. Very similar to case when, can be used to scale up multiple outputs.

```
df['c'] = np.select(
[
    (df['a'].isnull() & (df['b'] == 0))
], 
[
    1
], 
default=0 )
```

Comment: Thank you!  Whilst other answers give a better answer for the specific question; **this** is the best answer for a SQL `CASE...WHEN` equivalent.

Comment: i agree with @dsz this one is the best equivalent for case when statement

Answer (score 3):

You cant check series value is NaN using np.nan instead use series.isnull()

Below code gives desired output:

```
df['c'] = np.where(df['a'].isnull() & np.array(df['b'] == 0),1,0)
```

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference is to use pandas `apply` function with an if statement:

```
df['c'] = df.apply(lambda x: (1 if np.isnan(x[0]) and x[1] == 0 else 0), axis=1)
```

Comment: I've not tried it, but I suspect that this won't be performant as it's effectively an iteration rather than a vectorised operation.